# How to find variable string directly before definite string in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that finds a string in the last line of a log file (code below)

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (templog.log) do (
set var=%%a
)
echo !var! > string.log

findstr /m ":help" string.log >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo !var!
echo !var! >> output.txt
endlocal
goto NEXTCODE
)
```

What this does is it searches a log file for `:help` **in the last line** and if it finds it, it goes to the next section of code. Let's say the last line of the log file contains the following...

```
[11:13:55] [Example]: [Time] <Tag435> :help
```

In the case that the last line of a log file is the above, my program would detect that it includes `:help` and move on. In the next section of code I am trying to make it so it sets a variable to the word directly before `:help` which in this case is `<Tag435>`. Is there any way that this could be done? I have tried searching the vast internet and have found only ways to detect a specific word, and not the word before that specific word. I found this on another thread and modified it to my need...

```
set str1=!var!
if not x%str1:<Tag435>=%==x%str1% goto NEXTSECTION
```

But, in my log file, it won't always be `<Tag435>` right before `:help` so that means I would have to add an `if` statement for every possible word that could be before `:help` which I'd prefer not to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my breakdown:

First, find out how many lines are in the file:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=[]" %%a in ('find /N /V "" logfile.log') do ( set FILE_SIZE=%%a)
set /A LAST_LINE=%FILE_SIZE%-1
```

Look at that last line to see if it contains `:help`

```
more +%LAST_LINE% logfile.log | findstr /M ":help" > nul
```

If it does have the text `:help` in it, get the 6th token (the token right before "help")

```
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    for /F "tokens=6 delims=:<>[] " %%a in ('more +%LAST_LINE% logfile.log') do (
        echo(Found %%a before :help
    ) 
)
```

The output is: `Found Tag435 before :help`

---

The full script is:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=[]" %%a in ('find /N /V "" logfile.log') do ( set FILE_SIZE=%%a)
set /A LAST_LINE=%FILE_SIZE%-1

more +%LAST_LINE% logfile.log | findstr /M ":help" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    for /F "tokens=6 delims=:<>[] " %%a in ('more +%LAST_LINE% logfile.log') do (
        echo(Found %%a before :help
    ) 
)
```

Comment: When I run this, making sure to change all of the variables so that it works with my program, it outputs `Found Time before :help` when it should be `Found Tag435 before :help`

Comment: Then you have not described the format of your log-file accurately.  You should be able to get different elements by changing the `tokens=6` part.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Simply enough, all I had to do was change it to `tokens=7`! I'm marking this as the accepted answer and thanks again!